# I want to assign numbers to the listed elements in order

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting

In a bash script I've written, I'm listing the items one after another in a list. I want to add the sequence numbers to the beginning of these listed elements.

Code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARRAY=( 'New York' 'Dubai' Istanbul Amsterdam)

ELEMENTS=${#ARRAY[@]}

for (( i=0;i<$ELEMENTS;i++ )); do
   echo ${ARRAY[${i}]}
done
```

The output:

```
New York
Dubai
Istanbul
Amsterdam
```

My want output:

```
1. New York
2. Dubai
3. Istanbul
4. Amsterdam
```

How can I do this with bash scripting ? Thank you

Comment: @Milag I solved this problem with below answer, thank you

Comment: Your for loop can also be: `for i in "${!ARRAY[@]}"` to iterate over the indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
echo "$((i+1)). ${ARRAY[${i}]}"
```